# how to add sharing Button in recyler view item click?

Tags: android, android-studio

I m making a simple app which fetch the data through an API , I want to add a button on my recyler view to share the link of the image but when i click the share button my app craseh with below mentioned errors
My Adapter of recylerview :-

```
 public class Adapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList;

public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.modelArrayList = modelArrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view  = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false);


    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
     String memeUrl = modelArrayList.get(position).getUrl();
     holder.setImage(memeUrl);
     holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             Intent sharing = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
             sharing.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
             sharing.setType("text/plain");
             //  String sharebody = "Quizz time beautiful app";
             String subject = "Hey watch this cool meme Click this link "+memeUrl+"\n\n";

             sharing.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, subject);

            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharing, "Share using"));
         }
     });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return modelArrayList.size();
}

public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView memeImage;
    Button button;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        memeImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    }

    void  setImage(String link){
        Glide.with(context).load(link).into(memeImage);
    }
}
```

}

My Mainactivity :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
Adapter adapter;

ArrayList<Model> arrayList;
ProgressDialog dialog ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recylerview_id);

    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Getting Memes...");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();


    String url = "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/30";

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.v("MEMERESPONSE",response.toString());

                    try {
                        JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("memes");

                        Log.v("Arraycheckingxx", array.toString());

                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                           // Log.v("Arraychecking"+i, jsonObject.toString());
                            String url = jsonObject.getString("url");
                            Log.v("url"+i, url);
                            Model model = new Model(url);

                            arrayList.add(model);

                        }
                        Log.v("Arraychecking", String.valueOf(arrayList.size()));
                        adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayList);
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });






    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);


}
```

}

But when i clicked the button my app crashes with the below errors

```
ndroid.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:922)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:898)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:389)
    at com.choudhary.memegram.Adapter$1.onClick(Adapter.java:53)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
    at android.
```

Comment: How do you declare and set 'context' ?

Comment: i added the adapter and mainactivity please have a look?

Comment: Change the adapter constructor to: public Adapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList) then you have an activity to reference in your adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayList);` to

```
adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, arrayList);
```

You are using application context in adapter, but you need activity's context, so you dont need to add flag